# Skip image validation and creation in laravel update function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

Please am trying to upload 3 different images using the code below. How do I get each of the methods that generates the unique image names to run only when their respective request fields have data or is not empty. thus the form submit should not try generating any image name for afile field when that particular file field is empty.

My update controller function

```
public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
{
    $image = $request->file('primary_image');
    $name_gen = md5(rand(1000, 10000)).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();  

    Image::make($image)->resize(523,605)->save('upload/products/'.$name_gen);
    $save_url = 'upload/products/'.$name_gen;


$image_1 = $request->file('image_1');
$name_gen = md5(rand(1000, 10000)).'.'.$image_1->getClientOriginalExtension();  

Image::make($image_1)->resize(523,605)->save('upload/products/'.$name_gen);
$save_url_1 = 'upload/products/'.$name_gen;



$image_2 = $request->file('image_2');
    $name_gen = md5(rand(1000, 10000)).'.'.$image_2->getClientOriginalExtension();  

    Image::make($image_2)->resize(523,605)->save('upload/products/'.$name_gen);
    $save_url_2 = 'upload/products/'.$name_gen;


    Product::insert([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'category' => $request->category,
        'price' => $request->price,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'status' => $request -> status,
        'estimated_delivery_time' => $request->estimated_delivery_time,
        'available_quantity' => $request->available_quantity,
        'colors' => $request->colors,
        'supplier_name' => $request->supplier_name,
        'supplier_phone' => $request->supplier_phone,
        'video_description' => $request->video_description,
        'primary_image' => $save_url,
        'image_1' => $save_url_1,
        'image_2' => $save_url_2,


    ]);


    $notification = array(
    'message' => 'Product updated successfully',
    'alert-type' => 'success'
);

return redirect()->back()->with($notification);
```

}

Thanks so much for taking time to review my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are doing the same name generation process all through, you can use an array and do a `foreach` loop with an `if` condition like this:

```
$my_array = [$request->file('primary_image'), $request->file('image_1'), $request->file('image_2')];

foreach($my_array as $item) {
if($item) {
$image = $item;
    $name_gen = md5(rand(1000, 10000)).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();  

    Image::make($image)->resize(523,605)->save('upload/products/'.$name_gen);
    $save_url = 'upload/products/'.$name_gen;

}

}
```

Now this will only generate names for images that are not empty.

**UPDATE:**
For the insert functionality, I would assume your table fields for the images can have null values, so this doesn't throw an error. Now instead of the code above, do this:

```
$my_array = [$request->file('primary_image'), $request->file('image_1'), $request->file('image_2')];
$insert_array = [];
foreach($my_array as $item) {
$save_url = '';
if($item) {
$image = $item;
    $name_gen = md5(rand(1000, 10000)).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();  

    Image::make($image)->resize(523,605)->save('upload/products/'.$name_gen);
    $save_url = 'upload/products/'.$name_gen;
    

}
array_push($insert_array, $save_url);

}
```

Now for your insert query, do this:

```
Product::insert([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'category' => $request->category,
        'price' => $request->price,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'status' => $request -> status,
        'estimated_delivery_time' => $request->estimated_delivery_time,
        'available_quantity' => $request->available_quantity,
        'colors' => $request->colors,
        'supplier_name' => $request->supplier_name,
        'supplier_phone' => $request->supplier_phone,
        'video_description' => $request->video_description,
        'primary_image' => $insert_array[0],
        'image_1' => $insert_array[1],
        'image_2' => $insert_array[2],


    ]);
```

This would work.

Comment: Thank you so much Innovin. Please how do I save each individual image name to their respective database fields if I use this approach? Do I save each of them as save_url?

Comment: I will update my answer with that functionality

Comment: Your table fields for the images can contain null right?

Comment: Yes all three images have nullable fields in database

Comment: Also, this is an update function so it’s most likely that by the time this function is called the images might have had initial values inserted by the store function

Comment: I already tried something like that when you gave the first answer but I keep getting an error telling me to use get method instead of put

Comment: If you are updating something from the database then you should not be using the ```insert``` method. You should use ```Product::where('something', 'another thing')->update();```. I need to see your full code. You can contact me if you like via my profile.

Comment: Ok thank yo so much